# character in unity3d animation view is far away from center?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 3dsmax

in 3dMax the animation looks like this! seems likes fine

[image]

But After I export and import to Unity3D. In its animation view, It looks below

[image]

Comment: Removed Unity tag, this isn't for the game engine but for the Microsoft DI container.

Comment: I faced a similar problem with Blender. See if this helps you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object